# multiple value in column

Tags: java, sql

My code like this

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(
    "SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table where column2=name "); 
system.out.println(rs)
```

Is that correct? Or how do I, get the sum value from a column with SQL in java? Can you write a little example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(
   "SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table where column2=name "); 
System.out.println(rs);// this is wrong
```

this will print ResultSet object.

this should be

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(
   "SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table where column2=name "); 
if(rs.next()){
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
}
```

Comment: You are missing a call to `rs.next()`